# Split String With preg_split php

Tags: php, regex

I am having string like these

`selectedvalue == product || product condition || product flush then @"yes,no",selectedvalue == water || water condition || water flush then @"true,false"`.

Using some pattern inside preg split to get the resultant output in an array.

```
Array(
 0 => selectedvalue == product || product condition || product flush then @"yes,no"
 1 => selectedvalue == water || water condition || water flush then @"true,false"
);
```

Anybody can help this?

Comment: Anyone can suggest me to get the resultant output as mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$data='selectedvalue == product || product condition || product flush then @"yes,no",selectedvalue == water || water condition || water flush then @"true,false"';


$data=explode('selectedvalue',$data);

$myArray=[];
foreach($data as $row){
    $myArray[]='selectedvalue '.$row;
}

echo '<pre>';
unset($myArray[0]);
print_r($myArray);
```

You can try with explode to create an array. This is what this function was created for.

The output of the above code is :

```
Array
(
    [1] => selectedvalue  == product || product condition || product flush then @"yes,no",
    [2] => selectedvalue  == water || water condition || water flush then @"true,false"
)
```

It's a "dirty" solution but i think it will solve your issue. If you could split your records with a pipe would be much better, you could simple explode into pipe delimiter and have your array ready.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to get your result, you might match a comma using a positive lookahead `(?=selectedvalue)` to assert that what follows is `selectedvalue`:

```
$pattern = "/,(?=selectedvalue)/";
$string = 'selectedvalue == product || product condition || product flush then @"yes,no",selectedvalue == water || water condition || water flush then @"true,false';
var_dump(preg_split($pattern, $string));
```

That will give you:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(77) "selectedvalue == product || product condition || product flush then @"yes,no""
  [1]=>
  string(74) "selectedvalue == water || water condition || water flush then @"true,false"
}
```